# Save data when Windows 8 Store app closes

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I have written a windows 8 store app (XAML/C#) which I have running on a Microsoft surface. The app is basically a data entry application which doesn't have any save buttons. Saving is performed automatically when jumping between pages or when the application is suspended.

However one senario I can't seem to catch is when the user closes the application (when the users swipes from the top to bottom of the screen).

So at the moment I subscribe to App.Current.Suspending and call save here:

```
App.Current.Suspending += Current_Suspending;                  

void Current_Suspending(object sender, Windows.ApplicationModel.SuspendingEventArgs e)
{
    Save();
}
```

I also override the SaveState method and call Save here:

```
protected override void SaveState(Dictionary<string, object> pageState)
{
    Save();
    base.SaveState(pageState);
}
```

But niether of these methods are called when the application is closed.

Does anybody know of an event that gets fired when the app closes?

Thanks

Comment: Your use of the word "closed" when your talking about the application being suspended is a little confusing.  Can you determine if the Suspending event actually happens, if not, then you are not hooking into the event the correct way.  Seems like this article might help you do this the correct way: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh986968.aspx

Comment: The suspending event fires when the app is suspended but when it's closed it doesn't. When I say closed I mean the user is swiping the screen from top to bottom (or pressing Alt-F4)

Comment: Your suspension event only happens when the application is suspended not closed.  You need to handle the application actually permenantly closing by handling the event that happens when the application is closed.

Comment: I looked into the issue and **there isn't one.**

Answer (score 6):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh465115.aspx

At the bottom it contains the following note:

*A note about debugging using Visual Studio:  Visual Studio prevents Windows from suspending an app that is attached to the debugger. This is to allow the user to view the Visual Studio debug UI while the app is running. When you're debugging an app, you can send it a suspend event using Visual Studio. Make sure the Debug Location toolbar is being shown, then click the Suspend icon.*

Answer (score 3):

I hate to simple point to the documentation on a Windows Store Application lifecycle but the documentation is pretty clear.  There isn't a special event that handles when the application is closed by pressing ALT-F4 Windows Store Applications are suppose to be only suspended or simply not running.  This means you should handle saving the user's data ever so often and/or offer a way to save such data.

> There's no special event to indicate that the user has closed an app.
>   After an app has been closed by the user, it's suspended and
>   terminated, entering the NotRunning state within about 10 seconds. If
>   an app has registered an event handler for the Suspending | suspending
>   event, it is called when the app is suspended. You can use this event
>   handler to save relevant application and user data to persistent
>   storage.
>
> You should decide how your app behaves when it's activated after being
>   closed by the user. It may make no difference to you whether the app
>   was terminated by Windows or by the user. If your app needs to do
>   something different when it is closed by the user than when it is
>   closed by Windows, the activation event handler can determine whether
>   the app was terminated by the user or by Windows. See the descriptions
>   of ClosedByUser and Terminated states in the docs for the
>   ApplicationExecutionState enumeration.
>
> Apps shouldn't close themselves programmatically unless absolutely
>   necessary. For example, if an app detects a memory leak, it can close
>   itself to ensure the security of the user's personal data. When you
>   close an app programmatically, Windows treats this as an app crash.

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464925.aspx)